# Most battery efficient way of running a service at certain hours of the day?

Tags: android, service, background, gps

I want to create an android service that only runs between the hours 7:30AM till' 8:55AM. This service will query GPS to find out if it's in the correct location and if it is it will send one request to a server and then shutdown. What is the most battery efficient way to create a background service of this kind? Code examples are always greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `AlarmManager` to start your service up when needed. You'll need to implement a `BroadcastReceiver` in your `Service` and register it through your manifest (so it receives calls even when your service is not running).

After your service has done it's work (or once the given time is up) you can finish the Service by calling [`stopSelf()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopSelf%28%29) to release all resources.

This way your service is only running when required. It is also possible with `AlarmManager` to make it so that if the device is off it will be turned on when the alarm time is reached.

Comment: If you use an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) it should automatically stop once it runs out of work.

Comment: Thanks for the correction to stopSelf(). And yes you are correct about using an IntentService.